# Android: How do I get the token from facebook using firebase Auth 9.6.1 after successful login?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm loggin in using Firebase-UI using the facebook provider, and I would like to know how to get the token from them. I searched everywhere without any success, only finding javascript responses and not java. This is the code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_rrr,
            R.drawable.compass,
            R.drawable.bell,
            R.drawable.cloud,
            R.drawable.user_circle,
    };
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxxx/");
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private User user;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    private static final int FLOCKIN_PROVIDER = 1;
    private static final int FACEBOOK_PROVIDER = 2;

    Geocoder geocoder;
    String bestProvider;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    List<Address> usr = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Get the shared preferences
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean user_saw_presentation = preferences.getBoolean("onboarding_complete", false);
        // Check if onboarding_complete is false
        if (!user_saw_presentation) {
            // Start the onboarding Activity
            Intent intro = new Intent(this, intro.class);
            startActivity(intro);
            finish();
            return;

        }

        /*firebaseUser= auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            // already signed in
            getUserDataFromProvider(firebaseUser);

        } else {
            // not signed in
            sendUserToAuthenticationScreen();
        }*/


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( false );
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( true );
        //getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
        setupViewPager( viewPager );


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById( R.id.tabs );
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( viewPager );
        tabLayout.setTabGravity( TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL );
        setupTabIcons();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("Loggin state", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    getUserDataFromProvider(user);
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("Loggin state", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    sendUserToAuthenticationScreen();

                }

            }
        };



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        //just in case it doesn't work the disabling of the back button
//TODO:descomentar esto una vez que termine de probar
      /*  if (!preferences.getBoolean( "logged_in", false )) {
            sendUserToLogin();
        }*/
    }

    /*protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // user is signed in!
                Log.i("USER_AUTHENTICATION","LOGGED_IN");
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                // user is not signed in. Maybe just wait for the user to press
                // "sign in" again, or show a message
                Log.i("USER_AUTHENTICATION","LOGIN_FAILED");
                sendUserToAuthenticationScreen();

            }
        }
    }*/


    //it gets the user data from Firebase
    private void getUserDataFromProvider(FirebaseUser firebaseUser){


        user=new User(
                firebaseUser.getUid(),
                firebaseUser.getDisplayName(),
                firebaseUser.getEmail(),
                firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()
        );


        List<? extends UserInfo>  providers=firebaseUser.getProviderData();
        //which type of user,if thesecondelement comes
        String provider= providers.get(1).getProviderId();
        if(provider.equals("facebook.com")){
            user.setProvider(FACEBOOK_PROVIDER);
        }else if(provider.equals("password")){
            user.setProvider(FLOCKIN_PROVIDER);
        }
    }





    private void sendUserToAuthenticationScreen() {


        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setProviders(
                        AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                        AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)
                        //.setTheme(R.style.SuperAppTheme)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);


    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 0 ).setIcon( tabIcons[0] );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 1 ).setIcon( tabIcons[1] );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 2 ).setIcon( tabIcons[2] );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 3 ).setIcon( tabIcons[3] );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 4 ).setIcon( tabIcons[4] );

        tabLayout.getTabAt( 0 ).getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 1 ).getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( "#1976D2" ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 2 ).getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( "#1976D2" ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 3 ).getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( "#1976D2" ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
        tabLayout.getTabAt( 4 ).getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( "#1976D2" ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener( new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( "#1976D2" ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_home, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.logout:
              //logout logic
        }
        return true;
    }



    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new MainMyFloks(), "Floks");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainNearby(), "Explore");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainAlerts(), "Alerts");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainArchive(), "Archive");
        adapter.addFragment(new MainProfile(), "Profile");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

And I logged the info on this method and is getting correctly to my app after login:

```
private void getUserDataFromProvider(FirebaseUser firebaseUser){


    user=new User(
            firebaseUser.getUid(),
            firebaseUser.getDisplayName(),
            firebaseUser.getEmail(),
            firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()
    );

    Log.i("FIREBASE_ID",user.getFirebaseId());


    List<? extends UserInfo>  providers=firebaseUser.getProviderData();
    //which type of user,if thesecondelement comes
    String provider= providers.get(1).getProviderId();
    if(provider.equals("facebook.com")){
        user.setProvider(FACEBOOK_PROVIDER);
    }else if(provider.equals("password")){
        user.setProvider(FLOCKIN_PROVIDER);
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?. Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get facebook accessToken from firebase is very simple. I was using firebase auth UI. After authentication with facebook you will get basic information from firebase user object like display name, email,provider details. But if you want more information like gender, birthday facebook Graph API is the solution. Once user authenticated with the facebook you can get access token like this.

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

But sometimes it will give you NULL value instead of valid access token. Make sure that you have initialized facebook SDK  before that.

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
      }
   }
```

After initialization use graphAPI

```
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {

        System.out.println(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        try {
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String gender = object.getString("gender");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Access Token NULL");
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I could get the facebook access token and the facebook id of the current user by using this code after login in with firebaseUI that still doesn't return any token(from what I've seen they are working on returning the relevant token of the provider you used to authenticate yourself).....

CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

```
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
            Log.i("not_logged","0");
        } else {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN",AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken().toString());
            //save the token in shared preferences
            editor.putString("FACEBOOK_TOKEN",AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken().toString());
            String facebook_ID=Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId().toString();
            Log.d("FACEBOOK_ID",facebook_ID);
            editor.putString("FACEBOOK_ID",facebook_ID);
            editor.commit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

After a successful Firebase authentication, the device's token is generated and an `onTokenRefresh()` callback is delivered to the `FirebaseMessagingService`.

This is a sample from Google's Firebase Guide. Check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device) out for more info.

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked wonders. you forgot to mention to add the intent filter on the AndroidManifest XML. Do you save the token on the database or just on shared preferences?.....Just to be sure...is this the firebase token or the facebook token we are talking about?.....Cause I found this under the FCM section.....it never mention that is returning a facebook token

Comment: I think you made a mistake. This is the token of FCM...I just want to get the facebook access token from firebase....

Comment: I apologize, I thought you meant the FCM token. I haven't tried it, but [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/9fb5779c6037567228becdc24bc82466296b4eb0/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/provider/FacebookProvider.java) is an example from Firebase you might want to check out.

Comment: Don't worry, I already solved it, your answer was useful to my notifications so at least you helped in another aspect...I will post my answer

Comment: Wonderful. Good luck.